# React event listener callback functions don't use updated states

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When accessed from reDraw the resizableList is an empty array, when accessed from addImageClick it shows the actual array. the TextInput element contains a text input which calls eventBus.dispatch('addtext') on change.

So, after I add an image, I have two TextInput elements, and two Resizable elements. I change the text in one of the TextInput elements, empty state array. I trigger the add image button which logs the array before resetting it, array has two elements in it before reset.

```
import React,{useState,useRef,useEffect} from "react";
import Resizable from "./Resizable";
import TextInput from "./TextInput";
import eventBus from "../eventbus/EventBus";

export default function Meme(){


    
    const [image, setImage] = useState(new Image());
    const [resizableList, setResizableList] = useState([]);
    const hiddenFileInput = useRef(null);
    const cvs = useRef(null);

    
    function reDraw(){
        const width = 600*(image.width/image.height);
        const ctx = cvs.current.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1200, 600);
        ctx.drawImage(image,(1200-(width))/2,0,width,600);

        console.log(resizableList);

        for (let i=0;i<resizableList.length;i++){
            let el = document.getElementById(`${i}--textbox`);
            console.log('test');
        }

        console.log('ran');
        console.log(image);
    }
    
    
    function addResizable(width){
        let resizable = {
            cvs:cvs,
            imgwidth:width,
            image:image
        }
        setResizableList((prevResizableList)=>[...prevResizableList, resizable]);
    }
    
    function draw() {
        const width = 600*(image.width/image.height);
        const ctx = cvs.current.getContext("2d");
        console.log(image.width);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1200, 600);
        ctx.drawImage(image,(1200-(width))/2,0,width,600);
        addResizable(width);
        addResizable(width);
        
    };
    
    function addImageClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(resizableList);
        setResizableList([]);
        hiddenFileInput.current.click();
    };
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        eventBus.on('addtext',reDraw);
        image.onload = draw;
        console.log('useeffect');
    },[])

    return (
        <main>
            <form className="form">
                
                
                <div className='form--textboxes'>
                    {resizableList.map((item,index)=>{
                    return (<TextInput cvs={item.cvs} image={item.image} imgwidth={item.imgwidth} key={index} id={index}/>)
                })}
                    <button className='form--button--textboxes'>Add Text</button>
                </div>
                
                <button className="form--button" onClick={addImageClick}>Add Image</button>
                <div className="form--image">
                <canvas id='meme' ref={cvs} className="form--meme" height="600" width="1200"></canvas>
                {resizableList.map((item,index)=>{
                    return (<Resizable cvs={item.cvs} imgwidth={item.imgwidth} key={index} id={index}/>)
                })}
                </div>
            </form>
            <input
               type="file"
               name="myImage"
               style={{display:'none'}}
               ref={hiddenFileInput}
               onChange={(event) => {
               image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
              }}
            />
        </main>
    )
};
```

I apologize if the explanation above is too long. So far I've been able to get by just by reviewing questions, it's the first time I actually had to write one.

Update: What I basically want to do is loop over the resizableList array, and update the text on the canvas based on the position and size of each resizable. I know how to do that but I can't, because when I access the array from the reDraw function, the array shows as empty. I tried looking for alternatives but I couldn't find any. I create an id for each textbox/resizable of format: arrayindex--textbox and arrayindex--box. That's how the textboxes and resizables relate to eachother.

2nd Update: Sooooooo...

```
function addTextClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(resizableList);
}
function reDraw(){
    const width = 600*(image.width/image.height);
    const ctx = cvs.current.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1200, 600);
    ctx.drawImage(image,(1200-(width))/2,0,width,600);
    console.log(resizableList);
    button.current.click();
}
```

As I said previously, reDraw is triggered by an event fired by the text input's onChange. I also made this button which has the addTextClick as it's onClick. And yes, I trigger input's onchange, I get one empty array followed by one length 2 array(which is the resizableList array) in my console. ?????

I guess this kinda fixes my problem as I can just create a hidden button but this is more of a workaround and I would still like to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Updated with solution:

So, I ran into this same issue while working on some other functionality of my webapp.

The problem is that when you add an event listener the callback function is set with the state values present at the time. So it doesn't matter how many times your states are updated after setting the event listener, it's still going to use the states it had when it was set up.

Funny enough, after understanding what was causing the problem I found some posts from others running into this problem and using exactly the same workaround I used above, which is to create a reference to a hidden button and have the event listener's callback function trigger the onClick.

Another solution is to use the useEffect hook and recreate the event listener every time a state is updated, but in my case that doesn't really work that well since I have a lot of states that are updated constantly.